# How to check if a function/variable is defined in a header file using qmake?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt-creator, qmake

In `qmake` how can one figure out if a function/variable is defined in a header file during the configure (when running `qmake`) step?

Comment: qmake is particularly bad at config checks, consider using something like CMake.

Comment: I do not think that `qmake` even reads source files, so that it is not possible.